# how to add onclick event in the dive tag

Tags: html, css

```
       <div id="diagram"></div>
    <div class="get">
        <div class="arc">
        <span class="text">WebPlus</span>
            <input type="hidden" class="percent" value="95" />
            <input type="hidden" class="color" value="#DD9F51" />
        </div>
        <div class="arc">
            <span class="text">DrawPlus</span>
            <input type="hidden" class="percent" value="90" />
            <input type="hidden" class="color" value="#D84F5F" />
        </div>
        <div class="arc">
            <span class="text">PhotoPlus</span>
            <input type="hidden" class="percent" value="80" />
            <input type="hidden" class="color" value="#88B8E6" />
        </div>
        <div class="arc">
            <span class="text">PagePlus</span>
            <input type="hidden" class="percent" value="53" />
            <input type="hidden" class="color" value="#BEDBE9" />
        </div>
        <div class="arc">
            <span class="text">MoviePlus</span>
            <input type="hidden" class="percent" value="65" />
            <input type="hidden" class="color" value="#EAC58C" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is my div tag i call up the span tag value in arc class how to make the how to make this div as onclick tag

Comment: thats possibly asked hundred times on SO!

Answer (score 0):

`<div onclick="thisisafunction()" class="get">`

```
function thisisafunction() {
     doSomething;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

there are two steps

1]

```
<div onclick="function_name()">text</div>

function function_name() {
   //doSomething
}
```

2]

```
<div id="event">text</div>

$(function () {
   $('#event').on('click', function () {
        //doSomething
   )};
)};
```